# Making a clickable button in QGIS Attributes Form that is a URI from an Expression?

Tags: qgis, uri

I would like to make a clickable button in my Attributes Form that is a URI that is dynamically generated using an Expression Calculator from fields in the data.

I have already created an action for the Attributes Table, though for my implementation, this is insufficient, hence asking about a button for the Attributes Form.

Expression Calculation:

```
trim(concat('bingmaps:?q=',"PARCELADDRESS",', ',"PARCELADDRESSCITY",', ', "PARCELADDRESSSTATE",', ', "PARCELADDRESSZIPCODE"))
```

Generated URI:
`bingmaps:?q=123 Street Road, City City, State State, Zip Zip`

This URI button would be clickable in my attributes form so that I can easily link the user to an appropriate map view in a third party tool.

Here's my current form, sans URI button to launch Microsoft Maps on the user's PC:

[image]
QGIS Version Information:
3.12.1-București - 121cc00ff0

Comment: it is easier making an action, and using the actions tool on either geometry or attribute table to open a expression based url. Take a look at the default actions.

Comment: I know about actions, and have implemented the above as an action for the table. However, that's not a sufficient solution, as I need the button on the attributes form, as above.